# What's the origin of the naming of Euler equation in economics?

Tags: macroeconomics, mathematical-economics, history-economic-thought

In Economics, Euler equation is:

$u'(c_{t})=\beta Ru'(c_{t+1})$

What is the origin of the name of 'Euler' in this equation?

I know that, in fluid dynamics, Euler equation is

\begin{aligned}{D\mathbf {u}  \over Dt}&=-\nabla w+\mathbf {g} \\\nabla \cdot \mathbf {u} &=0\end{aligned}

However, I cannot catch the similarity between economics and fluid dynamics for the Euler equation.

Comment: There are dozens, if not hundreds, of Euler equations/identities/theorems in math, physics, engineering, economics, etc. It shouldn't be too surprising that there is another Euler equation in fluid dynamics.

Comment: My guess is that it came from the Euler-Lagrange equation in calculus of variation. When you are doing utility maximization in continuous time, you are basically doing *constrained* calculus of variation, aka optimal control.

Comment: @user141240 is correct.  Physics of the time was just discovering the Lagrangian in connection with optimal paths of particles, a completely separate view from the older Newtonian physics. Lagrange and Euler were contemporaries.  I think Euler was rumored to have said "there is no dynamics, where a choice is made of some trajectory, without optimization".  And economics is all about rational optimization of choices. https://scholarship.claremont.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1834&context=jhm

Answer (score 1):

This seems to address the question :

https://mitsloan.mit.edu/shared/ods/documents?DocumentID=4171

An Euler equation is a difference or differential equation that is an intertempo- ral first-order condition for a dynamic choice problem. It describes the evolution of economic variables along an optimal path. It is a necessary but not sufficient condition for a candidate optimal path, and so is useful for partially characterizing the theoretical implications of a range of models for dynamic behavior. In models with uncertainty, expectational Euler equations are conditions on moments, and thus directly provide a basis for testing models and estimating model parameters using observed dynamic behavior.

From : Euler equations∗ Jonathan A. Parker†
Northwestern University and NBER December 2007

Comment: Links break, please quote the gist of the answer from the source. Also name/credit the source.